# Gradle sync failed after converting build.gradle to build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have converted my build.gradle to build.gradle.kts . updated gradle files but it giving me error adnd error is **Unresolved reference: android**  *ScriptCompilationException(errors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: android, location=C:\Users\PureLogics.gradle.tmp\gradle-kotlin-dsl-11588424420843922281.tmp\build.gradle.kts (37:1)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: compileSdkVersion, location=C:\Users\PureLogics.gradle.tmp\gradle-kotlin-dsl-11588424420843922281.tmp\build.gradle.kts (39:5))*

```
    apply(plugin = "com.android.application")
    apply(plugin = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    apply(plugin = "android")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-android")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-android-extensions")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-kapt")
    apply(plugin = "com.google.gms.google-services")
    apply(plugin = "com.google.firebase.appdistribution")
    apply(plugin = "org.sonarqube")
    apply(from = "buildsystem/api.gradle")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions")
    apply(from = "../buildtype.gradle")

    android {
    //Don't update it without checking side effects
    compileSdkVersion(33)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.tinkerventures.prnondemand"
        minSdkVersion(21)
        targetSdkVersion(33) //Don"t update it without checking side effects
        versionCode = 94
        versionName = "0.0.94"//MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.layout_base_toolbar.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }


    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        register("releaseConfig") {
            storeFile = file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword = "prn_11"
            keyAlias = "prn_on_demand"
            keyPassword = "prn_11"
        }

    }


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        isAbortOnError = false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

     }
     dependencies {


    implementation project (path = " =openCVLibrary")
    implementation project (path = " =common")
    val androidX = "1.3.0"
    val retrofit = "2.9.0"
    val retroConverter = "2.9.0"
    val glide = "4.12.0"
    val lifecycle = "2.2.0"
    val butterKnife = "10.2.1"
    val SDP = "1.0.6"
    val permission = "2.2.2"
    val room = "2.3.0"
    val playServices = "18.1.0"
    val locationServices = "19.0.0"
    val multidex_version = "2.0.1"

    implementation fileTree (mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar")))
    implementation project (path = " =common")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1")

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidX")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")

    implementation("com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3")

    implementation platform ("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics") {
        exclude(module = "play-services-ads-identifier")
    }

    // GMS
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.0.0")
    // V3

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.1.1") //kotlin

    // val group: implementation = "com.google.android.libraries.maps", name = "maps", version = "3.1.0-beta"
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta")
    // Utilities for Maps SDK for Android (requires Google Play Services)
    implementation("com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.8.2")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9")

    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room")
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version")
    implementation("androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0")


    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$locationServices")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServices")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0")


    /*Retrofit dependencies powered by Square*/
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retroConverter")

    implementation platform ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit")

    annotationProcessor "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0"

    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0")
    annotationProcessor("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0")
    kapt("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0")

    /*Butter knife dependencies powered by Jake wharton*/

    implementation("com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnife")
    kapt("com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnife")

    /*SDP & SSP dependencies powered by intuit*/
    implementation("com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:$SDP")
    implementation("com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:$SDP")


    /*TED Permission dependencies powered by Android Open Source Community*/
    implementation("gun0912.ted:tedpermission:$permission")
    implementation("com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0")
    implementation("com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3")
    implementation("com.gmail.samehadar:iosdialog:1.0")

    implementation("com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.7")

    implementation("com.github.florent37:SingleDateAndTimePicker:2.2.5")
    implementation("com.github.stoyicker:aligningrecyclerview:1.0")


    implementation("me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar")
    implementation("com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0")

    implementation("com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.2")
    implementation("com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6")
    /**
     * Document Scanner
     */
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1")
    implementation("com.github.mayuce:AndroidDocumentScanner:1.5.3")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0")

    implementation("com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2")


    /*Testing Libs by Google*/
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.4.0")


}
```

^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public inline fun  TaskContainer.register(name: String, type: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>, configurationAction: Action<in TypeVariable(T)>): TaskProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Comment: I would suggest clearing all UI caches.  File > Invalidate Caches.  That fixes a lot of upgrade issues usually.

Comment: Tried many times does not work for me

Comment: it's claiming a reference in your build file is unresolved.  Also (side note) I see you're using opencv for document scanning.  I wrote a scanner for work using that program, with drag handles and edge detection.  The logic was onerous.